# Jira API not filtering on fields

Tags: api, jira

I can't seem to get my request results to filter on the field pass. No matter what I input I get this massive data dump from Jira. Nor does it seem to limit by the maxResults count. Here's the API call:

```
curl -u app_jira_docs:"xxxxxxxxxx" --url 'https://jira.xxxxxxxxx.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=10506&"name"="epic"&"fields"="summary"&startAt=0&maxResults=2' -H "Content-Type: application/json" | jq '.' --sort-keys
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a similar query to filter correctly by swapping a few of your parameters around and adjusting some of the formatting:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://jira-url/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project%3D10506%20AND%20name%3Depic&fields=summary&startAt=0&maxResults=2' --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

I grouped all of the JQL terms together, separated them with spaces and `AND` clauses, dropped the double-quoting around some of the parameters, and then URL encoded the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, I got there on my own but this is the correct answer.